# How to tell if the logged in user has a security role?

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to find out if the currently logged on user has a certain security role.  I've looked on Google (couldn't find an answer) and the SDk examples (they seemed way too complicated).  So, if you know the name of the security role and the user ID, how do you check to see if the user has that role?

Comment: "and the SDk examples (they seemed way too complicated)".....haha you will need to keep reading them until you understand.

Comment: So many questions -- are you coding a plugin? or a 3rd-party app? are you working in the client with JavaScript? Have you assigned a CRM Role to certain users or are you using an ASP.NET Role Provider? Please update the question. I agree with @Hanoncs. if you can understand the SDK examples -- keep at it. What have you tried? Did you encounter an exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you browse the folder structure of the CRM 2011 SDK (link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) to this location you will find what you are looking for:

> .\SDK\SampleCode\CS\BusinessDataModel\UsersAndRoles\DoesUserBelongToRole.cs

It provides a sample built as a C# Console application.  The code will work in ASP.NET as long as the app pool user is authorized to access the CRM Organization that you are trying to connect to.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find lots of examples out there. However to get the current users roles in JavaScript you can use:-

```
Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles()
```

That however will return a list of GUID's which you then need to compare with roles in the system.  This part is a bit trickier however here is an article that shows pretty clearly how to do it
http://www.infinite-x.net/2010/11/16/retreiving-user-roles-in-crm-2011/

At a high level you need to do an OData query (against RoleSet) to return the role (or roles) that you are wanting to compare.  Then you compare the GUID's of those roles against the GUID's returned by the getUserRoles() function and you're good to go!